# Can i return a Stream from a spring jpa repository using a querydsl predicate argument

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using spring data and have a repository that extends JpaRepository and QueryDslPredicateExecutor.  I get a list of entities from the repository by calling the Iterable findAll(Predicate p) method.   I was wondering, is it possible to get a Stream returned from the repository passing in a querydsl predicate as an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as described in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/1169#issuecomment-752400977, you can declare your own method that returns `List<...>`

```
import java.util.List;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;

@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends MongoRepository<MyEntity, ObjectId>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity> {

  List<MyEntity> findAll(Predicate predicate);
}
```

then simply

```
myEntityRepository.findAll(myPredicate).stream()....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't possible right now. Check this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-704

Comment: But this issue is about changing the return from `Iterable` to `List`

Comment: I think it says `List` or `Stream`